# Java : Builder Design Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have classes which has been autowired with all the attributes related to it. I need to return the object of these classes when a request for a particular class is received. A senior developer is suggesting to use the builder pattern. However the information I would be passing is just the request. I am confused can someone help.

```
Class DogDetailsProvider{

@Autowired
DogVendor dVendor;

@Autowired
DogOwner dOwner;

@Autowired
DogHealth dHealth;
}


Class CatDetailsProvider{

@Autowired
CatVendor cVendor;

@Autowired
CatOwner cOwner;

@Autowired
CatHealth cHealth;
}

Class ElephantDetailsProvider{

@Autowired
EleVendor eVendor;

@Autowired
EleOwner eOwner;

@Autowired
EleHealth eHealth;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you probably need something like `Service Locator Pattern`. It helps decide which object you have to use depending on particular request. It reduces boilerplate code when you want to access your services.

At first you have to create `interface` with accessor methods to your `vendor/owner/health` classes:

```
public interface DetailsProvider {

    Vendor getVendor();
    Owner getOwner();
    Health getHealth();

}
```

Your `DogDetailsProvider`, `CatDetailsProvider`, `ElephantDetailsProvider` have to implement that `DetailsProvider` interface. Also your `vendor/owner/health` classes have to have interface to keep inheritance mechanism.

Then you have to create service locator:

```
@Service
public class DetailsProviderLocator {

    private DetailsProvider dogDetailsProvider;
    private DetailsProvider catDetailsProvider;
    private DetailsProvider elephantDetailsProvider;

    @Autowired
    public DetailsProviderLocator(
            @Qualifier("DogDetailsProvider") DetailsProvider dogDetailsProvider, 
            @Qualifier("CatDetailsProvider") DetailsProvider catDetailsProvider, 
            @Qualifier("ElephantDetailsProvider") DetailsProvider elephantDetailsProvider) {
        this.dogDetailsProvider = dogDetailsProvider;
        this.catDetailsProvider = catDetailsProvider;
        this.elephantDetailsProvider = elephantDetailsProvider;
    }

    DetailsProvider getDetailsProvider(Animal animal) {
        switch(animal) {
            case CAT        : return catDetailsProvider;
            case DOG        : return dogDetailsProvider;
            case ELEPHANT   : return elephantDetailsProvider;
            default         : throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not allowed!");
        }
    }

}

public enum Animal {

    CAT, DOG, ELEPHANT;

}
```

Now depending on enum (which can be anything, depends on your request) your service locator will return specific service. It is also easy to extend, because of inheritance you can create new services and just add new value to enum.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Do I have to put qualifier in the dogdetailsprovider etc classes as well ?

Comment: You have to add qualifier, because you will have more than one bean of type `DetailsProvider `

Answer (score 0):

> I need to return the object of these classes when a request for a particular class is received

This sounds like you need getter methods for objects such as `dVendor`in classes like `DogDetailsProvider`. You can either add boilerplate code for the getter methods or use lombok's [`@Getter`](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter).

Builder pattern is used to create objects by exposing setter methods in a builder class for each of the attributes of the object which needs to be built. Since you need to "get" and not "set" any data, using the Builder pattern would not help at all.